# Google Map API - polygon cutted off from another polygon

Tags: google-maps, polygon

I'd like to draw polygon into the Google Map API and cut another polygon which lies inside the first one off. Is this possible? Could you give me any example, please (maybe link to the page with working example)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to create a Donut with Javascript API V3(Empty space inside like a hole)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846529/i-want-to-create-a-donut-with-javascript-api-v3empty-space-inside-like-a-hole)

Comment: Thank you very much, it could help and I'll use this method. I found a mention about "holes" in the Google Map API documentation, but I don't know, how to use it: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.Polygon

Comment: Maybe, here is better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901830/multipolygon-creating-the-hole-effect-with-google-map-v3